# compare array of object of array with an another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

have two arrays one with a simple array with all the elements have integer value and another one with array of objects with an array (nested object).

need to compare both the array and remove the value which is not equilant.

```
 let userValue = [
    {
      userName: 'Abby Jerin',
      tiers: [
        { tier_name: 'Colorado', errors: [], tier_agent_id: '115867' },
        { tier_name: 'MidSouth', errors: [], tier_agent_id: '115897' },
        null,
      ],
    },
    {
      userName: 'Alvin Lu',
      tiers: [
        {
          tier_name: 'Frisco West',
          errors: ['is publish disabled'],
          tier_agent_id: '111257',
        },
        {
          tier_name: 'MidSouth',
          errors: ['is publish disabled'],
          tier_agent_id: '116526',
        },
        null,
      ],
    },
    {
      userName: 'Alfie Gonzalez',
      tiers: [
        {
          tier_name: 'Hillsboro',
          errors: ['is publish disabled'],
          tier_agent_id: '111481',
        },
        {
          tier_name: 'MidSouth',
          errors: ['is publish disabled'],
          tier_agent_id: '116527',
        },
        null,
      ],
    },
    {
      userName: 'Amanda Prather',
      tiers: [
        { tier_name: 'South King County', errors: [], tier_agent_id: '111506' },
        { tier_name: 'Dallas', errors: [], tier_agent_id: '114530' },
        {
          tier_name: 'Cypress Champion Forest',
          errors: [],
          tier_agent_id: '114532',
        },
        null,
      ],
    },
  ]

  let checkedValue = [115867, 115897, 111506, 114530, 114532]
```

compare checkedValue with the `tier_agent_id` remove the tiers object if the `tier_agent_id` and checkedValue are not same

Comment: what about `null`?

Comment: dont consider that. do u have any solution for that as I'm new to this

Comment: What is the expected output? What will the output if only one `tier_agent_id` is present in the `checkedValue`?

Comment: Should it remain as it is or it is discarded in the final result?

Comment: if the value present in the checkedValue doesn't match the `tier_agent_id ` then dont return that particular object

Comment: final results wanted to be like this
``

Comment: @decpk wants to discarded in the final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
userValue.map((obj) => ({
  ...obj,
  tiers: obj.tiers.filter(o => o && checkedValue.includes(Number(o.tier_agent_id))),
}))
```

```js
let userValue = [{
    userName: "Abby Jerin",
    tiers: [{
        tier_name: "Colorado",
        errors: [],
        tier_agent_id: "115867"
      },
      {
        tier_name: "MidSouth",
        errors: [],
        tier_agent_id: "115897"
      },
      null,
    ],
  },
  {
    userName: "Alvin Lu",
    tiers: [{
        tier_name: "Frisco West",
        errors: ["is publish disabled"],
        tier_agent_id: "111257",
      },
      {
        tier_name: "MidSouth",
        errors: ["is publish disabled"],
        tier_agent_id: "116526",
      },
      null,
    ],
  },
  {
    userName: "Alfie Gonzalez",
    tiers: [{
        tier_name: "Hillsboro",
        errors: ["is publish disabled"],
        tier_agent_id: "111481",
      },
      {
        tier_name: "MidSouth",
        errors: ["is publish disabled"],
        tier_agent_id: "116527",
      },
      null,
    ],
  },
  {
    userName: "Amanda Prather",
    tiers: [{
        tier_name: "South King County",
        errors: [],
        tier_agent_id: "111506"
      },
      {
        tier_name: "Dallas",
        errors: [],
        tier_agent_id: "114530"
      },
      {
        tier_name: "Cypress Champion Forest",
        errors: [],
        tier_agent_id: "114532",
      },
      null,
    ],
  },
];

let checkedValue = [115867, 115897, 111506, 114530, 114532];

const result = userValue.map((obj) => ({
  ...obj,
  tiers: obj.tiers.filter(o => o && checkedValue.includes(Number(o.tier_agent_id))),
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: but why u added that css `.as-console-wrapper ` ? i'm  confused

Comment: Ignore it. It is just to get the full height of the output when you click `Run code snippet`?

Answer (score 1):

Another option, longer, but a little more readable than it does

```
const isChecked = value => checkedValue.some(item => item === value);
  
const hasChildren = tier => tier !== null && isChecked(Number(tier.tier_agent_id));
    
const filtered = userValue.filter(e =>
    e.tiers.some(tier => hasChildren(tier)));
    

console.log(filtered);
```

```js
let userValue = [
    {
      userName: 'Abby Jerin',
      tiers: [
        { tier_name: 'Colorado', errors: [], tier_agent_id: '115867' },
        { tier_name: 'MidSouth', errors: [], tier_agent_id: '115897' },
        null,
      ],
    },
    {
      userName: 'Alvin Lu',
      tiers: [
        {
          tier_name: 'Frisco West',
          errors: ['is publish disabled'],
          tier_agent_id: '111257',
        },
        {
          tier_name: 'MidSouth',
          errors: ['is publish disabled'],
          tier_agent_id: '116526',
        },
        null,
      ],
    },
    {
      userName: 'Alfie Gonzalez',
      tiers: [
        {
          tier_name: 'Hillsboro',
          errors: ['is publish disabled'],
          tier_agent_id: '111481',
        },
        {
          tier_name: 'MidSouth',
          errors: ['is publish disabled'],
          tier_agent_id: '116527',
        },
        null,
      ],
    },
    {
      userName: 'Amanda Prather',
      tiers: [
        { tier_name: 'South King County', errors: [], tier_agent_id: '111506' },
        { tier_name: 'Dallas', errors: [], tier_agent_id: '114530' },
        {
          tier_name: 'Cypress Champion Forest',
          errors: [],
          tier_agent_id: '114532',
        },
        null,
      ],
    },
  ]

let checkedValue = [115867, 115897, 111506, 114530, 114532]
  
const isChecked = value => checkedValue.some(item => item === value);
  
const hasChildren = tier => tier !== null && isChecked(Number(tier.tier_agent_id));
    
const filtered = userValue.filter(e =>
    e.tiers.some(tier => hasChildren(tier)));
    

console.log(filtered);
```